# Can I generate application style specific scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a rails application with a specific style, some contained outside the application.css file. How can I generate a new scaffold section in my app, with the rails scaffold command, that following the style for the first part of my app.

Will I always end up with the same plain scaffolding style? Or maybe using scaffolding midway through a project is a best practice no no, if that is the case I would like to know as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only worried about styling you should be fine. The scaffolding generator will generate a scaffold.css file but that doesn't mean you have to ever link to that or use that. Just be sure to include your other styles in the layout instead of the auto generated styles.